# Can't find proper relation and architecture saving data in ROOM

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I have a user table like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
    data class Users(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fullName") val fullName: String
    ...
 )
```

Now I have event information from REST

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "eventName": "Event name",
  ...
  "participantList": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "status": "going"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "status": "interested"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I save this in Room and what should be the entities and relations so that I can have a Event enitity with list of users and each users status. for example

```
data class Event(
  val id:Int,
  val eventName: String,
  val participantList: List<UserWithStatus>
)

data class UserWithStatus(
  val user:User,
  val status:String
)
```

Comment: Parse the json data into object.. make object of event and insert the event in database.iniside DAO class , you should have a query like this 
    @Insert
    void insert(Event events);
once you have parced the json object. like 

 val event= response.body()
mydatabase.eventdao().insert(event)

Comment: I can do that, but the problem was I can get user id from REST which I can save but when I query it how can I get event information with users information for related user

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should use [nested relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships) in your case.

Try next schema (you can add Foreign Keys if you wish):

**Entities**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey var id: Int,
    var fullName: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "event")
data class Event(
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int,
    val eventName: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "event_details")
data class EventDetails(
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int,
    val eventId: Int, // make it Foreign Key if you want
    val userId: Int,  // make it Foreign Key if you want
    val status:String
)
```

**Auxiliary classes**

```
data class UserWithStatus(
    val userId:Int,
    val status: String,
    @Relation(
        entity = User::class,
        parentColumn = "userId",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val user: User

)

data class EventWithUser(
    @Embedded
    val event: Event,
    @Relation(
        entity = EventDetails::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "eventId"
    )
    val participantList: List<UserWithStatus>
)
```

**DAO**

```
@Query("select * from event")
fun getEventsWithUsers(): List<EventWithUser>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sergiy . will try like this and let you know.